# Run test after finish of some parallel tests in a test suite

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng

In TestNG.XML, given **parallel** Tests `A`, `B`, `C`, we need to run test  `D` only after completion of both tests `A` and `B` and in parallel with test `C` (if still running).

**Update**
Here is the desired execution, Tests over time.

```
 [1]    [2] [3]   [4]  [5] 
A |------|
B |----------|
C |----------------|
D            |----------|


tests run in parallel, points with number indicated the following actions:

[1] Tests A, B and C are started.
[2] Test A finishes
[3] Test B finishes, Test D started <the desired behaviour>
[4] Test C finish < we SHOULD NOT wait C finish to strt Test D>
[5] Test D finish
```

**Update 24-08-2018**  I opened an issue [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1904).

TestNG currently doesn't support such behavior, I have to workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dependsOnMethods = {"A","B","C"}` with @Test annotation at D.

```
@Test(description = "This is test D",dependsOnMethods = {"A","B","C"})
```

Comment: `A` and `B` are Tests in testng.xml file (not test methods) , also I need test `D` not to wait `C` to finish, the idea is to save time and let `D` run as soon as both `A` and `B` are finished.

Comment: you can not define method dependency in testng.xml, so alternatively you should define groups on these tests and define group dependency on testng.xml. Also if you don't want to wait for C, simply don't include it in same group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about test methods A,B,C,D. Then you can fix it by dependsOnMethods or dependsOnGroups of @Test annotation.

```
public class ClassName{

    @Test(groups = { "AB"})
    public void testA() {}

    @Test(groups = { "AB"})
    public void testB() {}

    @Test
    public void testC() {}

    @Test(dependsOnGroups={"AB"})
    public void testD() {}
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="test suite">

    <test name="test" parallel="methods">
        <classes>
            <class name="here.is.your.ClassName" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

If you are talking about test which is child of suite, then it seems no way to manage dependency among tests. But you can still try to use group to manage test methods in different tests, and then use dependsOnGroups to manage dependency among groups.